# Can I write a C# method that will terminate execution of anyone who calls it (within the same class)?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# class that is typically executed in a thread.  The caller can call a .Cancel method to stop the execution of the thread.

The ".Cancel" method will set a boolean "Cancelled" property to "True".  The actual cancellation comes from little blocks like this, scattered all over the place in my code:

```
public void ThisGetsExecutedAsAThread()
{
.....

    DoThing1;
    if (Cancelled)
    {
        LogMsg = "Cancelled!";
        Finished = true;
        return;
    }
    DoThing2;
    if (Cancelled)
    {
        LogMsg = "Cancelled!";
        Finished = true;
        return;
    }
    DoThing3;
    if (Cancelled)
    {
        LogMsg = "Cancelled!";
        Finished = true;
        return;
    }
.....
}
```

This approach works quite well (i.e., the caller can cancel the action, and the execution stops within a few seconds), but as you can see it is quite repetitive.

I'd like to replace those blocks with something more like this:

```
...Do some action...
TerminateIfCancelled;
...Do some action....
```

Is it possible to define a "TerminateIfCancelled" that will cause the caller to return?

Or have I missed some much better general solution to this problem..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way to end a thread is return from its function, and there are only 2 ways of returning from a function - `return` and `throw`, so if you don't like `if(Cancelled) return;` you can define new exception type (`CancelledException` for example) and throw it in your `TerminateIfCancelled`:

```
sealed class CancelledException : Exception { }


private void TerminateIfCancelled()
{
    if (Cancelled)
    {
        LogMsg = "Cancelled!";
        Finished = true;
        throw new CancelledException();
    }
}

public void ThisGetsExecutedAsAThread()
{
    try
    {
        DoThing1;
        TerminateIfCancelled();
        DoThing2;
        TerminateIfCancelled();
        DoThing3;
        TerminateIfCancelled();
    }
    catch(CancelledException)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you further simplify this and just throw the CancelledException instead of calling TerminateIfCancelled()? Then in the catch block you would set LogMsg="Cancelled" and Finished=true.

Answer (score 1):

Get the thread instance that you created and abort it from another thread:

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(someDelegate));
oThread.Start()
```

and on your "CancelButton_Click":

```
oThread.Abort()
```

It will raise a ThreadAbortedException on the Thread. You should catch that exception and fail gracefully.

Comment: This seems like a good answer, but it would just be whateverThread.Abort() in the caller, otherwise you'd just be writing if (cancelled) { CurrentThread.Abort() } everywhere instead.

Comment: That was the point, to make it clear I edited the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

C# will help you with cancel/error/continue actions if you use [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) or [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx)